# What syntax is needed to fix this php unit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

Never php unit tested before - looked at multiple stack overflow posts still cant get it working.

[Output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH9Ft.png)

```html
<?php

namespace UnitTestFiles\Test;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FirstTest extends TestCase {
    

public function FirstTest() {
  $sscoretest1 = 10;

$sscoretest2 = $sscoretest1 / 20 * 100; 

echo $sscoretest2; 
  
   require('test.php');
   $this->expectOutputString('50');
}

}

?>
```

[EDIT output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZl86.png)

Comment: _In what way_ is it not working? What _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? If so, what are the exact errors? If not, how does the actual result differ from the expected result? What debugging have you already done?

Comment: I'm just looking to do one basic unit test for school testing documentation purposes, when I run PHP unit it outputs no tests executed in netbeans. I don't know what syntax is required to get it to run

Comment: The assumption here is that you are using a third party like PHPUnit. You should say this in the question, along with the version. Assuming PHPUnit, have you read and tried the Getting Started docs over there? You should try this from a command line before trying to coerce an IDE to do things. One step at a time.

Comment: Not sure if it is your only problem, but I'm pretty sure test function names are supposed to start with "test".  And it seems that `expectOutputString()` is supposed to be called _before_ the output is produced, not after.

Comment: @jdv I've looked can't quite get the syntax right or to get it to output im a complete beginner

Comment: @PatrickQ It didn't work its throwing errors thanks anyway there is an image above in the edit with the output window

Comment: You have two potential problems: running PHPUnit (if this is what you are using) and getting it to run from an IDE. Solve one problem first.

Comment: [Edit] the question and  _show your errors_! Follow the PHPUnit docs (IF that is what you are using) and make sure the basic test of "run PHPUnit as they describe to get the results" works before you do anything else. Work from the known to the unknown. Remember, you are asking us why some third-party software does not run _in your environment_ with few details for context. This means _you_ have to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: Also, no one wants to look at images of text output, which should be presented as searchable, copyable, formatted text in the question itself.

Comment: https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/phpunit-beginner-part-1-get-started